# should I move /bin and /lib folders that's inside a program to /usr/local/?

Tags: binary

I've downloaded IntelliJ idea IDE from their website. I've putted it inside `/usr/local/bin` and then configured my PATH var and the program work correctly. the program folder has these two folders inside it, bin and lib. I know that if I moved their content to my `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/lib/` the program will work. However, it will be a problem to remove it later because I won't be able to distinguish its files from what was already there inside `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/lib/`. I know that software centre doesn’t keep them in folders but it sprat them to `/usr/bin`, `/usr/lib` and other folders.

So my question is in what way should I organize these type of programs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't fix what ain't broken. There's no real need to move those files anywhere. (Or is there?) So, leave as it is.

If you want to do something fancy, create a `deb` package from it so you can easily install and uninstall.